# delete null value from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am working on JSON, now i have new issue create, when i'm delete an item from JSON it will delete the all item on that index after this on that place null are inserted now my problem is i want also index of that JSON object

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/LjgcK/23/)

In this Fiddle these step follow (Please follow this step):

1. Add item in cart
2. Now click on Go to cart.
3. Now click delete button

A alert box generate, see the first index of JSON it will be show null, i want delete that index from JSON

Comment: Shouldn't delete just remove all items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will work

`objArray.splice(0,1);`

Comment: if you really want to remove the first element of the array without leaving a null element.

Comment: I'm not just want delete first item, any item will be remove depend on user

Comment: so you want to delete all items at once?

Comment: no depend on user like 1,2 or 3.. but one at a time

Comment: so every time you click on delete it deletes one more object?

Comment: you are understand what i'm trying to say.. see i have delete button on the front of each item like if i click on second button then second item will be remove like that

Comment: then just iterate the objArray.splice(0,1); function
the first variable, (0,1), (1,1), (2,1) and so on

Comment: first number is the index of the array

Comment: yes now your capture my point nice one

Comment: yay ;)  give me some love then

Comment: still face some problem..

Comment: if i want remove 2 element then what can i do i have a variable id=2 and method is obj.splice() then what i do

Comment: 2 elements? then you say (index, 2) second variable defines how many objects u want to remove

Comment: it 2 not the no of element its the order of element in this case second element

Comment: i give up ;)  i am having a hard time understanding your english, i am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** remove `[0]` from `delete objArray[0]`.

http://jsfiddle.net/LjgcK/24/

**Edit**

When i click on delete button its show me json.

```
[{"id":1,"title":"ABC","image":"http://fiddle.jshell.net/LjgcK/24/img/HKP.jpg","description":"Example"}]
```

Comment: not work in your jsfiddle

Comment: @Subhash when i checked its show me json array in alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to remove an element from an array.

Comment: splice method only interchange the value not remove

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to '[shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)' elements from the array instead of deleting them.

http://jsfiddle.net/LjgcK/25/

```
$('#btnDelete').click(function () {
   objArray.shift();
    alert(JSON.stringify(objArray));
});
```

Comment: sorry shift only remove from one end, if i want second element remove then what i'm doing

Answer (score 0):

that becoz you are working with array not with object so to remove from array try this

```
 objArray.splice(0, 1);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LjgcK/26/)