# how to delete null values in array of json objects

Tags: javascript

I have JSON object in following structure,

```
var i=[];

i={"details":"personal", "about":[null,{"Name":"prudhvi","age":"26"},

                                       {"Name":"siva","age":"28"}

]

}
```

In the following object, how to delete that null? Can you please give code for that.

Thank you in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete null value from json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587966/delete-null-value-from-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise, if you don't know the position within an array, simply write :

```
i.about = i.about.filter(function(x){return x !== null});
```

**ES6 Syntax**

```
i.about = i.about.filter(x => x !== null);
```

**UPDATE SUMMARY**

Updated according to @nnnnnn comment. Thanks @nnnnnnn.

Hope it helps

Comment: Wouldn't you need `i.about = i.about.filter(...);`? `.filter()` creates a new array. (But +1 because `.filter()` is neater than the `for` loop with `.splice()` that I used in my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have a "JSON object" because [there is no such thing](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). What you have is an object.

Second, note that assigning `i = [];` is pointless when you then assign `i = /*something else*/` on the line after.

Anyway, if you know that the `null` value will always be the first element in the `about` array then just do this:

```
i.about.splice(0,1);
```

To find and remove any and all `null` values wherever they may be in the `about` array:

```
for (var j = i.about.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    if (i.about[j] === null)
        i.about.splice(j, 1);
```